# Mount a Samba share using Kerberos ticket

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mount, samba, kerberos

I have a Samba server (which is the domain controller), and a Ubuntu 14.04 Client with a logged user who is authenticated by Kerberos (the client joined to domain with Likewise). The user want to access a network share with this command:

> mount.cifs //DOMAIN/PATH /HOME/USER/PATH -o sec=krb5

But with (or without) 'sec' parameter, the mount command prompts for password. If I type my password, I can mount the share, but I want to mount without password.

How can I do it with my valid Kerberous ticket?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are signing in with a windows domain user a Kerberos ticket is already requested. You can test it by executing `klist`.

To reuse this ticket you have to add `user` and `cruid` option to your mount order. This way you do not have to enter any credentials again.

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o user=$USER,cruid=$USER,sec=krb5 //domain/path /home/path
```

To mount the share with your user as owner (and thus with write permission) add the `gid` and `uid` options.

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o user=$USER,cruid=$USER,sec=krb5,gid=$GID,uid=$UID //domain/path /home/path
```

You get your `$GID` by running `id -g $USER` and your `$UID` by `id -u $USER`.

It may be that you have to `apt-get install keyutils` to get this working.

Answer (score 4):

First, try `-o vers=1`. The kernel's SMB2 client has only [very recently](https://git.kernel.org/linus/ceb1b0b9b4d1089e9f2731a314689ae17784c861) gained Kerberos support – in Ubuntu 14.04, only the 4.4.x kernel will have it.

Second, check if the `request-key` and `cifs.upcall` binaries are installed and that the latter is mentioned in `/etc/request-key.conf` (or `/etc/request-key.d/`):

```
create cifs.spnego * * /usr/bin/cifs.upcall %k
```

Finally, check the system log (`/var/log/debug` or `journalctl -b`) for messages from cifs.upcall, and make sure it is looking for your tickets in the correct place. It doesn't actually *know* which process is accessing the share and what $KRB5CCNAME it has, so it needs to guess a few common places.

In fact, if you run `mount` via sudo, the mounting process (running as uid 0) won't have *any* tickets by default; a separate `sudo kinit` may be required.

Comment: Now things are better, but it doesn't work yet. It prints: mount error(126): Requried key not found. But if I run klist, the command run successfully.

Comment: "echo $KRB5CCNAME" command is prints nothing to console.

Answer (score 1):

One more tip. Auto-mounting share with Kerberos needs that required keys are loaded/updated in Kerberos cache. I've found that the most reliable way is to refresh cache right before mounting, with Systemd unit.
Created file `/etc/systemd/system/kinit.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Refresh Kerberos Token
After=syslog.target network.target
Before=mnt-backup.mount
Before=mnt-backup.automount

[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/kinit -R -kt /etc/krb5.keytab 'LINUX-CLIENT$@DOMA.IN'

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
WantedBy=mnt-backup.mount
WantedBy=mnt-backup.automount
```

And then issue

`systemctl daemon-reload`
`systemctl enable kinit.service`
`systemctl restart remote-fs.target`

Comment: This could use [k5start](https://www.eyrie.org/~eagle/software/kstart/).